# cin.ignore() can not remove input buffer

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a problem that `cin.ignore()` can not remove input from the buffer.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    using namespace std;

    int x=0;
    string k;
    cin >> x;
    cin.ignore(100,'\n');
    cin.clear();
    cin >> k;
    cout << k << endl;
}
```

For the above code:

```
input : abc (program ends when I just input abc)
output : abc
```

I was really surprised because `cin.ignore()` did not remove `"abc"` from the input buffer.

What is wrong with my code?

If I change the positions of `cin.ignore()` and `cin.clear()`, it works well, why is that?

Comment: `cin` is in an error state when you try to do `cin.ignore(100,'\n');`.

Comment: thank you for the comment !!!

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```cpp
int x=0;
cin >> x;
```

Causes `cin` to be put into an error state (specifically, the [`failbit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate) flag is set) if the input is not convertible to an `int`.

Per [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com):

[std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::operator>>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt):

> This function behaves as a [*FormattedInputFunction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FormattedInputFunction). After constructing and checking the sentry object, which may skip leading whitespace, extracts an integer value by calling [`std::num_get::get()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/num_get/get).
>
> ...
>
> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), `value` is left unmodified **and `failbit` is set**.
> (until C++11)
>
> If extraction fails, zero is written to `value` **and `failbit` is set**. For signed integers, if extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in `value`, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` or `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` (respectively) is written **and `failbit` flag is set**. For unsigned integers, if extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in `value`, `std::numeric_limits<T>::max()` is written **and `failbit` flag is set**.
> (since C++11)
>
> ...

Thus, any further I/O operations on the stream are disabled, like [`ignore()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore), until you [`clear()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the error state to re-enable I/O.

[std::basic_ios<CharT,Traits>::clear](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear):

> Sets the stream error state flags by assigning them the value of `state`. By default, assigns `std::ios_base::goodbit` **which has the effect of clearing all error state flags**.

[std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

> `ignore` behaves as an [*UnformattedInputFunction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction). After constructing and checking the sentry object, it extracts characters from the stream and discards them until any of the following conditions occurs:
>
> ...

[C++ named requirements: *UnformattedInputFunction*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/UnformattedInputFunction):

> An *UnformattedInputFunction* is a stream input function that performs the following:
>
> - Constructs an object of type `basic_istream::sentry` with automatic storage duration and with the `noskipws` argument set to `true`, which performs the following
>
>   - if `eofbit` or `badbit` are set on the input stream, sets the `failbit` as well, and if exceptions on `failbit` are enabled in this input stream's exception mask, throws `ios_base::failure`.
>   - flushes the `tie()`'d output stream, if applicable
> - Checks the status of the sentry by calling `sentry::operator bool()`, which is equivalent to `basic_ios::good`.
> - If the sentry returned `false` or sentry's constructor threw an exception:
>
>   - **sets the number of extracted characters (`gcount`) in the input stream to zero**
>   - if the function was called to write to an array of `CharT`, writes `CharT()` (the null character) to the first location of the array
>
> ...

Comment: thank you !!! so, cin.ignore() does not work when cin is in error state??

Comment: @Stephen correct. All I/O operations are disabled until the error state is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

`cin.clear();` removes the error flag from `cin`
and `cin.ignore();` ignores the next numbers of spaces.
Since you declared `x` as a Integer and you write it in first, the console expects that an integer to be read first. if you type `abc` at first instead you are typing in a string and the console returns an error flag because it expects an integer. That's why your program ends right after that.
If you put `cin.clear();` right after `cin>>x` and type `abc` the error flag that is been thrown will be ignored and the console continues with `cin>>k`